# XBMC Reads only 994 movies out of 1024

Tags: xbmc

I have 1024 Movies but XBMC only shows 994. In what file can I find information about which movies were not correctly read so I can check for format, coder and other video details. All movies for what I can see I have 4 container formats: 606 Movies in AVI, 3 in M4A, 105 in MKV and 310 MP4.

Comment: Finally, been trying to fix this a week. Using the missing movie script I was able to see which movies were missing but not how to fix them! This worked...for some reason even though my filename was named 2012, in XBMC it was named 2011 and wouldn't locate. Changed via your method and bam, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly there were some movies that xbmc looked at, but did not understand well enough to put them into your movie library.

Basically you have to use the "files" view. The problem is finding it. It is annoyingly well hidden, despite being an incredibly useful feature. It's location depends a bit on which xbmc skin/settings you are using, but there may be a "files" tab under "videos" or "movies" in the main menu. If not, go to your movie library and to the ".." (parent directory) twice.

As far as I understand, the (internal) video menu system in xbmc works like this:

**Top level menu**:

- Movies
- Recently added movies
- Files (the one you want)
- Playlists
- Video add-ons

If you select the **Movies** menu item you get:

- Genres
- Title
- Year
  ..etc

If you select the **Title** menu item, you will see your normal movie library.

So, it seems the "movies" menu item on the xbmc *main* menu really is a link to an internal submenu that is two levels further down from the root menu. And it is the root menu you want, in order to find the magic and elusive "files" view.

Once you find it, you should see a list of **ALL** your movies, where in your case a few of them are displayed by filename instead of the movie name. If the movies have their own subdirs you will have to enter the subdir to see if the movie title was detected or not. Normally some movies are not detected because xbmc doesn't understand their file name.

Once you have highlighted one of your missing movies, hit **C** on the keyboard to access the context menu. Then select **movie information**, and you should be able to enter a new title for the movie. Play around with that until the internet scraper finds your movie, and voila!, it's finally loaded into the library.

Phew.

Final note: If you have movies that do not exist in the lists of the internet scraper, it is possible to manually create movie meta data on the file system that xbmc can read instead. See here: [XBMC Wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Adding_videos_to_the_library/Home_videos/custom_videos)

Comment: Yes the "File" menu showed the movies at the top that were not correctly added. Some had wrong years, others had correct year but tmdb or imdb had wrong years, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the filename of your movie file is not enough for xbmc to determine the corresponding movie. The answer by Yngvefaen is good, but searching for the missing movies manually can take a lot of time.
Instead you can also install filebot (http://filebot.sourceforge.net/), you can use it to rename your movie files using information from for example themoviedb or imdb.
It works very well and after that xbmc will pick them up without problems. I suggested using the command line mode since it will let you do the process recursively.

Answer (score 0):

If you use...and ...instead of & for a movie that requirs & your movie will not be found.
If you have the wrong year associated with your movie it may not be found.
If you have any spelling errors in your movie title it may not be found.
If you use a -  (dash) in your title it may not be found ect.
If you have dvd title sometimes it looks for ....Video and comes up with Videodrome??

good luck.